# Create A Magnifying Glass Effect For All Webpage Content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do something like, on button click display a magnifying glass for all webpage content and the second button click would close the magnifying glass.

Just wondering is it possible to create a magnifying glass effect for any entire webpage content possibly using HTML5, JQuery, CSS3?

I looked up some examples, but they all have a large image and small images or a canvas. I want to use it on the entire content for any website, not just images...is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Have you tried something and are having trouble making it work? This question is overly broad in its current form. Please read [ask] for information on what makes a good question here.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely possible through the use of the **Zoomooz.js** library: http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

To make this work, you need to first download that JavaScript library and reference the parts that you’ll need:

**HTML Inclusions**

```
<head>
    <title>Zooming Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sylvester.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="purecssmatrix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.animtrans.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zoomooz.js"></script>
</head>
```

**JavaScript**
This targets the class “zoom” and applies the “zoomTo” method from the library. Then, by applying the same thing to the body, it allows the user to click outside of any element to zoom back out to the normal level. To expand this, apply the “zoom” class to any elements that you want to be zoomable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".zoom").click(function(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   $(this).zoomTo();
   });
   $(window).click(function(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   $("body").zoomTo();
   });
   $("body").zoomTo();
});
```

**HTML**
Next, create a container to be affected by the zoom features:

```
<body>
      <div id="container">
      <div id="outer" class="zoom">
      <div id="inner" class="zoom">
      <p><a href="#">Click here to zoom</a></p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**
Then, apply sizes and positioning to each div element. (#inner must utilize *position: absolute* in order for this to work)

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 70px;
}
#inner {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

(optional) Text styling:

```
#inner p {
text-align: center;
font: 25px/200px Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#inner p a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#inner p a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Modification**
You should have 3 separate zoom layers to navigate through. You can modify the CSS to zoom in on a wider area like you want. Adding or removing div elements will determine how many zoom levels you have.

**Reference:** http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/create-an-awesome-zooming-web-page-with-jquery/